# regex matching outer braces in python

Tags: python, regex, pcre

I have some f5 config data string formatted with nested braces as follows:

```
profiles {
    /Common/http { }
    /Common/serverssl {
        context serverside
    }
    /Common/tcp { }
    SOME_CRED_MGMT.DOMAIN_some_date {
        context clientside
    }
}
rules {
    /Common/X-FORWARDED-FOR
}
snat {
    pool SOME_SNAT.POOL
    type snat
}
```

I want get from the above group a list something like:

> ```
> some_list = ["profiles{..}", "rules{..}", "snat{..}"]
> ```

After searching I found something like (in JS):

```
profiles {([\s\S]*?)^}
```

And also similar (in PCRE):

```
({((?(?={)(?R)|[^}])*)})
```

But they don't work for Python. How to do a similar thing in Python?

Comment: You can use this https://regex101.com/r/rhp9ib/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the JS regex. You just need to edit it a little bit.

```
.+ {[\s\S]*?^}
```

I replaced `profile` with `.*` so that it does not only match `profile { ... }`. I also, made the group non-capturing, since you don't care about what's inside the curly braces. You just want the whole thing.

And then you can call `findall` to get the list you want:

```
matches = re.findall(r".+ {(?:[\s\S]*?)^}", test_str, re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: `I also, made the group non-capturing, since you don't care about what's inside the curly braces. You just want the whole thing` why not get rid of capturing group itself ?